# How to gather one element per row

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Say I have the following tensor:

```py
t = tf.convert_to_tensor([
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8]
])
```

and I have another index tensor:

```
i = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0],[2]])
```

how can i *gather* those elements saying that the `[0]` refers to the first array and `[2]` to the second one? thus getting as result `[[1],[7]]`?

I was thinking concatenating the indexes with a incremental value, to get`[[0,0],[1,2]]`, like this:

```
i = tf.concat((tf.range(i.shape[0])[...,None] , i), axis=-1)
tf.gather_nd(t, i)
```

but I feel there is a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use TensorFlow variant of NumPy's `take_along_axis`,

```
tf.experimental.numpy.take_along_axis(t, i, axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm always pretty skeptical about experimental, mainly because I have to take gradients on that resulting vector...

Comment: gradients should not be a problem, `take_along-axis` does whatever method you posted in your question. You can also use `one.hot` conversion of indices to mask and then pick the values as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple stack `i` with `tf.range(...)` as follows

```py
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.convert_to_tensor([
  [1,2,3,4],
  [5,6,7,8]
])
i = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 2])

length = tf.shape(i)[0]
indices = tf.stack([tf.range(length), i], axis=1)
# [0, 0], [1, 2]]

tf.gather_nd(t, indices)
# [1, 7]
```

I'm not sure there is an essentially better solution.

Comment: isn't the solution that I've posted in the question the same?